# Replace attribute in object in list --Python

Tags: python, list

How i can update attribute in object , and the object is in list

```
class kas:
    nom ="a"
    p1=""
    p2=""
    def __init__(self,nom,p1,p2):
        self.nom = nom
        self.p1=p1
        self.p2=p2

    @staticmethod
    def acoter(nom,b1,b2,maliste):
        newlist=list()
        for i,k in maliste:
            if nom==k.nom:
                 maliste.remove(i)
                 k.p1[0]=b1[0]
                 k.p2[0]=b2[0]
                 maliste.insert(i, k)
```

How i can update the element p1 in my object k and update him in my maliste ?

Comment: can you tell something about what the type of ```maliste``` argument should be?  in ``` for i, k in maliste ```, does ```k``` is the meaning of kas object? and is i is just an index?  I wonder that what's the content of ```maliste```

Comment: maliste=list()  and i put in maliste.append(k)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emm....I don't know if I catch your question.  Do you mean that you want to update element *p1* in the object *k*, and this *k* in maliste is also update?

I would recommend re-writing the acoter method like this:

```
@staticmethod
def acoter(nom, b1, b2, maliste):
    for i, k in enumerate(maliste):
        if kas.nom == k.nom:
            k.p1[0] = kas.b1[0]
            k.p2[0] = kas.b2[0]
```

Because maliste is `list()` and you just append the object `k` to the list, so I suspect the `for i,k in maliste:` will throw out an error.

To update a object's property in a list, you can just get the reference of the object and update it's property.  So I think you don't need to remove from maliste and insert this updated object into maliste list again.  And also, the **newlist** list is un-needed.